# Test sending email in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, automated-tests, integration-testing

I want to test my services in spring which should send emails.
I try to use `org.subethamail:subethasmtp`.

To acieve my goal I created service `MySender` where I send email:

```
@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

//...
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo("example@example.com");
    message.setSubject("Subject");
    message.setText("Text");
    mailSender.send(message);
// ...
```

To test this piece of code I created test `application.properties` (in test scope):

```
spring.mail.host=127.0.0.1
spring.mail.port=${random.int[4000,6000]}
```

And test configuration class which should start Wiser SMTP server and make it reusable in tests:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Wiser wiser;

    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    String smtpHost;

    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    int smtpPort;

    @Bean
    public Wiser provideWiser() {
        // provide wiser for verification in tests
        Wiser wiser = new Wiser();
        return wiser;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeMailServer() {
        // start server
        wiser.setHostname(smtpHost);
        wiser.setPort(smtpPort);
        wiser.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdownMailServer() {
        // stop server
        wiser.stop();
    }

}
```

Expected result is that application sends email using Wiser smtp server and verify number of sended messages.

But when I run service application throws `MailSendException(Couldn't connect to host, port: 127.0.0.1, 4688; timeout -1;)`.
But when I add breakpoint and try connect using telnet smtp server allow to connect and don't throw `Connection refused`.

Do you have any idea why I can't test sending mails?

Full code preview is available on github:
https://github.com/karolrynio/demo-mail

Comment: At a guess, the wiser server hasn't finished starting when the test executes.  You may need to do something in a `@Before` to make sure the socket is active before you run the test.

Comment: I'm not sure about it because in logs I have information that server is started before logs from tests, but I try wait for server started before run tests.

Comment: I found error. Cause of my problems was configuration. Line: spring.mail.port=${random.int[4000,6000]}, because spring inject 2 different values to beans. Bean MailSender have different port value than Wiser. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem. If using some constant port number for `spring.mail.port` in test Spring configuration combined with Maven tests forking, it resulted in tests randomly failing on port conflict when starting Wiser. 
As noted here in comments, using random.int doesn't help - it returns different value each time it's referenced, and it's expected behavior (see this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7009)).
Hence, we need a different way to initialize `spring.mail.port` with a random value, so it would be constant within the test execution. Here's a way to do it (thanks for advice [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7759)):

First, we may not set `spring.mail.port` in test properties file at all. We'll initialize it in `TestPropertySource`. We'll need a class like this:

```
public class RandomPortInitailizer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        int randomPort = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
        TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(applicationContext,
                "spring.mail.port=" + randomPort);
    }
}
```

Now we can run our tests this way (not too different from what's found in OP):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = RandomPortInitailizer.class)
public class WhenEmailingSomeStuff {
    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    String smtpHost;
    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    int smtpPort;

    @Before
    public void startEmailServer() {
        wiser = new Wiser();
        wiser.setPort(smtpPort);
        wiser.setHostname(smtpHost);
        wiser.start();
    }

    @After
    public void stopEmailServer() {
        wiser.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testYourJavaMailSenderHere() {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the application properties can you also add

```
mail.smtp.auth=false
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
```

The change your code to have these extra two values

```
 @Value("${mail.smtp.auth}")
 private boolean auth;

 @Value("${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}")
 private boolean starttls;
```

and put these options in your initializeMailServer

```
Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
wiser.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
wiser.setHostname(smtpHost);
wiser.setPort(smtpPort);
wiser.start();
```

let me know if this worked for you

Comment: I check it later. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I found other library for testing sending emails and I try it.

Comment: What is that library